# Accessing variables via Ansible 2.0 callback

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I inherited a callback plugin that was woirking with Ansible 1.9. We upgraded to 2.1 and it no longer works.

Looks like it's trying to access the playbook object but it's not getting passed into "v2_playbook_on_stats." My Python is rusty so I'm not sure how I can go about accessing that data. I'm tryijng to access the "extra-vars" variable but it's giving me the following error:

```
[WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_playbook_on_stats) in callback plugin
(</home/deployment/scripts/playbooks-2.0/callback/log_to_mongo.CallbackModule object at 0x2b8cf90>): 'NoneType'     object has no attribute 'extra_vars'
```

## code

```
class CallbackModule(object):
    """
    An ansible callback module for saving Ansible output to a database log
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.playbook = None
        self.playbook_name = None
        self.play = None
        self.task = None

def v2_playbook_on_stats(self, stats):
    global jira_ticket
    global deployed_modules
    global ocd_job_id
    global environment_id

    deployed_modules = []
    jira_ticket = self.playbook.extra_vars['jira_ticket']
    ocd_job_id = self.playbook.extra_vars['ocd_job_id']
    environment_id = self.playbook.extra_vars['environment_id']
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to guess what are you trying to achieve.
But ansible is cool also because you can always peek into it's source code.
Take a look at [slack.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/slack.py) callback plugin.

`extra_vars` and `playbook` access:

```
def __init__(self, display=None):

    ...

    if cli:
        self._options = cli.options

    ...

def v2_playbook_on_start(self, playbook):
    self.playbook_name = os.path.basename(playbook._file_name)

    ...

    extra_vars = self._options.extra_vars

    ...
```

If you need to use `playbook` object later in `v2_playbook_on_stats`, assign `self.playbook = playbook` when in `v2_playbook_on_start`.

Comment: Ah I think that's my issue. I tried assigning `self.playbook` in `v2_playbook_on_stats` instead of `v2_playbook_on_start`. I'll give it a shit later. I'm trying to access the extra cars within `v2_playbook_on_stats`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the extra vars passed by command line you have to use the

You have to use the variable manager objects:

```
def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):

    self.playbook_on_play_start(play.name)
    self.current_play = play
    self.vm = play.get_variable_manager()
```

And then you can access to this object for getting the vars:
    def v2_playbook_on_stats(self, stats):

```
    self._display.banner("##########  start of debug    ############")
    for key in debug_vars.keys():
        self._display.display("var %s --> %s" % (key, debug_vars[key]))
    self._display.banner("##########    end of debug    ############")

    self._display.banner("##########    debug hostvars    ############")
    for key in debug_vars['hostvars']:
        self._display.display("var %s --> %s" % (key, debug_vars['hostvars'][key]))

    self._display.banner("##########    debug localhost    ############")
    localhost = debug_vars['hostvars']['localhost']
    for key in localhost:
        self._display.display("var %s --> %s" % (key, localhost[key]))
```

The results will be something like that:

```
##########  start of debug    ############ ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
var playbook_dir --> /Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/playbooks
var ansible_playbook_python --> /Users/XXXXXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7
var groups --> {'all': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': [], 'local': ['localhost']}
var omit --> __omit_place_holder__e834e30aa3812ca0793e60c4024e1b54b5fb28b3
var ansible_version --> {'string': '2.8.4', 'full': '2.8.4', 'major': 2, 'minor': 8, 'revision': 4}
var ansible_check_mode --> False
var ansible_diff_mode --> False
var ansible_forks --> 25
var ansible_inventory_sources --> ('/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts',)
var ansible_skip_tags --> ()
var ansible_run_tags --> ('all',)
var ansible_verbosity --> 0
var hostvars --> {'localhost': {'inventory_file': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts', 'inventory_dir': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local', 'ansible_user': 'ansible', 'ansible_connection': 'local', 'ansible_python_interpreter': '/usr/bin/env python', 'inventory_hostname': 'localhost', 'inventory_hostname_short': 'localhost', 'group_names': ['local'], 'ansible_facts': {}, 'voyager_extra_vars2': {'uno': 'esto es una prueba', 'dos': 22, 'tres': 666666, 'cuatro': 'esto es otra prueba'}, 'voyager_extra_vars3': {'uno': 'esto es una prueba', 'dos': 2222, 'tres': 666666, 'cuatro': 'esto es otra prueba'}, 'test_var_play_2': 'Esto es una prueba de var en el play 2', 'playbook_dir': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/playbooks', 'ansible_playbook_python': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7', 'groups': {'all': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': [], 'local': ['localhost']}, 'omit': '__omit_place_holder__e834e30aa3812ca0793e60c4024e1b54b5fb28b3', 'ansible_version': {'string': '2.8.4', 'full': '2.8.4', 'major': 2, 'minor': 8, 'revision': 4}, 'ansible_check_mode': False, 'ansible_diff_mode': False, 'ansible_forks': 25, 'ansible_inventory_sources': ('/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts',), 'ansible_skip_tags': (), 'ansible_run_tags': ('all',), 'ansible_verbosity': 0}}

##########    end of debug    ############ ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

##########    debug hostvars    ############ ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
var localhost --> {'inventory_file': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts', 'inventory_dir': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local', 'ansible_user': 'ansible', 'ansible_connection': 'local', 'ansible_python_interpreter': '/usr/bin/env python', 'inventory_hostname': 'localhost', 'inventory_hostname_short': 'localhost', 'group_names': ['local'], 'ansible_facts': {}, 'voyager_extra_vars2': {'uno': 'esto es una prueba', 'dos': 22, 'tres': 666666, 'cuatro': 'esto es otra prueba'}, 'voyager_extra_vars3': {'uno': 'esto es una prueba', 'dos': 2222, 'tres': 666666, 'cuatro': 'esto es otra prueba'}, 'test_var_play_2': 'Esto es una prueba de var en el play 2', 'playbook_dir': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/playbooks', 'ansible_playbook_python': '/Users/XXXXXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7', 'groups': {'all': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': [], 'local': ['localhost']}, 'omit': '__omit_place_holder__e834e30aa3812ca0793e60c4024e1b54b5fb28b3', 'ansible_version': {'string': '2.8.4', 'full': '2.8.4', 'major': 2, 'minor': 8, 'revision': 4}, 'ansible_check_mode': False, 'ansible_diff_mode': False, 'ansible_forks': 25, 'ansible_inventory_sources': ('/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts',), 'ansible_skip_tags': (), 'ansible_run_tags': ('all',), 'ansible_verbosity': 0}

##########    debug localhost    ############ *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
var inventory_file --> /Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts
var inventory_dir --> /Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local
var ansible_user --> ansible
var ansible_connection --> local
var ansible_python_interpreter --> /usr/bin/env python
var inventory_hostname --> localhost
var inventory_hostname_short --> localhost
var group_names --> ['local']
var ansible_facts --> {}
var voyager_extra_vars2 --> {'uno': 'esto es una prueba', 'dos': 22, 'tres': 666666, 'cuatro': 'esto es otra prueba'}
var voyager_extra_vars3 --> {'uno': 'esto es una prueba', 'dos': 2222, 'tres': 666666, 'cuatro': 'esto es otra prueba'}
var test_var_play_2 --> Esto es una prueba de var en el play 2
var playbook_dir --> /Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/playbooks
var ansible_playbook_python --> /Users/XXXXXXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/python3.7
var groups --> {'all': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': [], 'local': ['localhost']}
var omit --> __omit_place_holder__e834e30aa3812ca0793e60c4024e1b54b5fb28b3
var ansible_version --> {'string': '2.8.4', 'full': '2.8.4', 'major': 2, 'minor': 8, 'revision': 4}
var ansible_check_mode --> False
var ansible_diff_mode --> False
var ansible_forks --> 25
var ansible_inventory_sources --> ['/Users/XXXXXXXX/projects/voyager/inventories/local/hosts']
var ansible_skip_tags --> []
var ansible_run_tags --> ['all']
var ansible_verbosity --> 0
```